# Python and SSL error loading tiles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, maptiler, ssl-error

I've a fresh and first install of QGIS on my desktop

QGIS version : 3.22.13
OS: Windows 10 pro, build 19044.2251

When I try to load some tiles from maptiler this error popup:

> Une erreur est survenue lors de l'éxécution du code Python:
>
> requests.exceptions.SSLError:
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.maptiler.com', port=443): Max retries
> exceeded with url: /maps/basic/style.json?key=PERSONNALKEYREPLACED
> (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, 'A failure in the SSL library occurred
> (_ssl.c:1129)')))  Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.13\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
> line 670, in urlopen
> httplib_response = self._make_request(   File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.13\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
> line 381, in _make_request
> self._validate_conn(conn)   File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.13\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
> line 978, in *validate_conn
> conn.connect()   File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.13\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py",
> line 362, in connect
> self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(   File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.13\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl*.py",
> line 386, in ssl_wrap_socket
> return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)   File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.13\apps\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in
> wrap_socket
> return self.sslsocket_class._create(   File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.13\apps\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in
> _create
> self.do_handshake()   File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.13\apps\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in
> do_handshake
> self._sslobj.do_handshake() ssl.SSLError: A failure in the SSL library occurred (_ssl.c:1129)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.13\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py",
> line 439, in send
> resp = conn.urlopen(   File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.13\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
> line 726, in urlopen
> retries = retries.increment(   File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.13\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py",
> line 446, in increment
> raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause)) urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError:
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.maptiler.com', port=443): Max retries
> exceeded with url: /maps/basic/style.json?key=PERSONNALKEYREPLACED
> (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, 'A failure in the SSL library occurred
> (_ssl.c:1129)')))
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users/a.vignacq/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis-maptiler-plugin\browser_mapitem.py",
> line 76, in
> lambda: self._add_raster_to_canvas())   File "C:\Users/a.vignacq/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis-maptiler-plugin\browser_mapitem.py",
> line 127, in _add_raster_to_canvas
> if not self._is_apikey_valid() and data_key == 'raster':   File "C:\Users/a.vignacq/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis-maptiler-plugin\browser_mapitem.py",
> line 106, in _is_apikey_valid
> if not utils.validate_key(apikey):   File "C:\Users/a.vignacq/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis-maptiler-plugin\utils.py",
> line 11, in validate_key
> response = requests.get(testurl + apikey)   File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.13\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py",
> line 76, in get
> return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)   File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.13\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py",
> line 61, in request
> return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)   File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.13\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py",
> line 530, in request
> resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)   File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.13\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py",
> line 643, in send
> r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)   File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.13\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py",
> line 514, in send
> raise SSLError(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.maptiler.com', port=443): Max retries
> exceeded with url: /maps/basic/style.json?key=PERSONNALKEYREPLACED
> (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, 'A failure in the SSL library occurred
> (_ssl.c:1129)')))
>
> Version de Python : 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52)
> [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]  Version de QGIS : 3.22.13-Białowieża
> Białowieża, 02ff117c
>
> Chemin Python : C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.13/apps/qgis-ltr/./python
> C:/Users/a.vignacq/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
> C:/Users/a.vignacq/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
> C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.13/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins C:\Program
> Files\QGIS 3.22.13\bin\python39.zip
> C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.13\apps\Python39\DLLs
> C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.13\apps\Python39\lib C:\Program Files\QGIS
> 3.22.13\bin C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.13\apps\Python39 C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.13\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages
> C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.13\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32
> C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.13\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
> C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.13\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
> C:/Users/a.vignacq/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python

Any idea how to resolve this?